# How to get time from time picker using jQuery and convert into ms-sql time(7) format?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to get time from time picker using java-script and convert into ms-sql time(7) format.

This Is my time picker code :

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                In Time
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="tpInTime" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that you only need to get the exact time format of time 7 (i found the format documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql)). So i decided to make this tricky trick.

***Assumption***

- Second and Millisecond is 0
- Getting the time using a timepicker ( not using Date() )

***Logic***

- Get the value of your time picker (look at the query)
- The value should be `hh:mm`
- According to Time 7 format, it should be `hh:mm:ss.ms`
- So i just merge `hh:mm` with `:ss.ms` (look at the query)
- Then i store it into a variable `time7`, and show it

***Reminder***

> Timezone is set to default (GMT+0)

Have a try!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
    In Time
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="time" id="tpInTime" value="00:00">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn default" type="button" id="btn"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">TEST</i></button>
        <p id="output"></p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var x = $("#tpInTime").val();
    var time7 = x+':00.0000000'
    $("#output").text(time7);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Tnx @Rizkita . It's a good idea . But i want something like [var startDate = $("#txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate").toISOString("yyyy-MM-dd").slice(0, -14);] . :)       .  And it's not dateTime ,it's time(7) something like [13:01:01.1234567]. Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: Hi @t_rex you may see my answer again, i updated it with some explanation. it should solve your problem even without using any "hard code". Good luck :)

Comment: Tnx Bro. @Rizkita .

Comment: No worries. Goodluck @t_rex